# trouble building opencv on fc15

Tags: ros, opencv, rosmake, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build desktop-full on an FC15 machine. After dealing with the boost/filesystem issues, opencv is giving me trouble now:

```
In file included from /opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/src/precomp.hpp:55:0,
                 from /opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/build/modules/core/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:354:13: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
In file included from /opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/src/precomp.hpp:55:0,
                 from /opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/build/modules/core/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2600:13: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2623:24: error: declaration of ‘operator[]’ as non-function
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2623:22: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2623:34: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘i’
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2626:36: error: declaration of ‘operator+=’ as non-function
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2626:32: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2626:46: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘ofs’
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2628:36: error: declaration of ‘operator-=’ as non-function
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2628:32: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2628:46: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘ofs’
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2641:5: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2642:15: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ has not been declared
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2661:13: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2684:21: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ has not been declared
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2687:37: error: declaration of ‘operator+=’ as non-function
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2687:33: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2687:47: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘ofs’
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2689:37: error: declaration of ‘operator-=’ as non-function
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2689:33: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2689:47: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘ofs’
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2733:22: error: declaration of ‘operator[]’ as non-function
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2733:20: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2733:32: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘i’
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2736:32: error: declaration of ‘operator+=’ as non-function
/opt/ros/diamondback/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2736:28: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
```

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10822/trouble-building-opencv-on-fc15/) by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9115 on 2011-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2011-08-04**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/996/boost-symbols-not-found?answer=1689#1689

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-08-04**:
What do you mean by "After dealing with the boost/filesystem issues"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution was to add

```
#include <stddef.h>
```

above all the includes in modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-08-06**:
There's a similar ticket at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5054

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-08-04**:
This shouldn't be necessary. I'd worry that solving this issue in that way would be masking the source problem. (Though I've no idea what the source problem would be)